# How to install QMYSQL plugin

Tags: qt, qtsql

As the question says, how to install QMYSQL plugin?
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, QtSDK 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/sql-driver.html#qmysql) tell you how to build and install it.